# how to get back all fields of a record in a many to many relationship

Tags: django

I have these tables:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    agreed_contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, through='ContractPartyInvolved')


class ContractPartyInvolved(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    agreed = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to query to get all the *contacts* linked to a specific *contract* so I have done this in my view:

```
def generate_contract(request, id):
    contract = get_object_or_404(Contract, pk=id)
    agreedContacts = contract.agreed_contacts.all()

    return render_to_response('contract.html', {'agreedContacts' : agreedContacts })
```

Now in my template I have:

```
  {% for ac in agreedContacts %}
       <strong> {{ ac.agreed }} || {{ ac }}</strong>
  {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that **I'm only getting back the name**, the {{ ac }} works correctly but I'm not getting back all the other fields associated to that record. For example agreed and role. **How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in view:

```
involved_contacts = contract.contractpartyinvolved_set.all()
```

in template:

```
{% for icontact in involved_contacts %}
    <strong> {{ icontact.agreed }} || {{ icontact.contact }}</strong>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ac` is a `Contact` instance, not a `ContractPartyInvolved` one. So `ac.agreed` won't work (unless you also have an `agreed` field on Contact, which you don't show).

Instead of following the ManyToMany relationship and getting `contract.agreed_contacts.all()`, you want to follow the reverse ForeignKey from Contact to CPI. From there you can access all the fields on CPI, and also continue following the relationship to Contact and get the contact name:

```
cpis = contract.contractpartyinvolved_set.select_related().all()


{% for cpi in cpis %}
    {{ cpi.agreed }} || {{ cpi.contact.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that I've used `select_related` on the initial query, to save further db hits as you know you're going to be following the relationship. If you don't want to access Role as well, you can limit the select_related by specifying `select_related('Contact')`.

Comment: +1 for select_related. Forgot about further db hits to retrieve the contact from the cpi. Thanks.